# Showing that a solid of revolution is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure, solid-of-revolution

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$, bounded and in the right half-plane:  $(r,z) \in E \Rightarrow r >0.$ $R(E)$ is rotating around the $z$-axis.

$$R(E):=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \space| \space(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z) \in E \}$$

How do I show that $R(E)$ is Lebesgue-measurable in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

---

I think I have to do something with characteristic functions and the transformation theorem. Then I could choose a smart diffeomoprhism but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $F:\Bbb{R}\times (0,\infty)\times\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^3$ defined by $F(\phi,r,z):= (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,z)$. Then, $F$ is $C^{\infty}$, hence locally Lipschitz, so it sends Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets. What can you deduce about the revolved set $R(E)$ in relation to $F$?

Comment: Hm.. I don't know :(, can you tell me?

Comment: no. Think about it: cylindrical coordinates mean you're literally rotating about an axis in a cylindrical fashion. what I'm saying in the last line is the revolved set $R(E) $ equals $F(A)$ for some set $A$. There is a very natural thing to guess for $A$. What is it?